# How to connect android app to specific class in html code?

Tags: java, php, android, html, json

I'm going to make an Android app for my university that in my app's login page the user or student could type his/her student code and student password and by clicking "log in" the app takes him/her to his/her own portal on website!

I've watched many tutorials but all of them used JSON Parsing.
Our university website doesn't have JSON file so I want to try to connect to HTML code of log in page straightly and by the way university won't let me to connect to website database.

Basically I just want to know how to connect my app's login page to that login class of website HTML code!

Here is the webpage, you can see what I said here by just right clicking and selecting "view page source" in chrome:

http://puya.toos.ac.ir/gateway/PuyaAuthenticate.php

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is , call the same page as you call **http get service** after getting the response , parse the html response.

For this specific case , you can login and track the script being called for login **post request** ,  call the same script by posting the required data **as http post service** . After authentication parse same result . Basically you will do all the parsing which browser do for you , and you have to present parsed data in meaning full manner .

You can also use webview for easy parsing and presentation.

Simulate your request by tracing every step of your website.

[image]